# GsonRequestBodyConverter.java line 47 causing a lot of ANRs and 99% of them occurs on Android 12

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

In our app, this issue has 286454 ANR events affecting 182342 users just in last 90 days.
It's mostly happening in Android 12 (%99).
I couldn't find out why this causes ANR yet

We are using GsonConverter like this:

```
Retrofit
.Builder().
...
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
```

And here is our retrofit and ohttp3 implemetations

```
// Retrofit & Okhttp3
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.3'
implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.9.1') {
exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
}
implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0') {
exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
}
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0'
```

I've opened a issue about this too.

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3765

Can someone help me with this issue?

[Crashlytics Dashboard of this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ9iH.png)

[Event Summary - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rET0F.png)

[Event Summary - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOTzr.png)

Comment: have you looked at the logs?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the ANR myself 
And from crashlytics, screenshots that i posted in decription is all i have actually

Comment: Could you please add a link to this StackOverflow question to your GitHub issue as well, to prevent people from answering your question twice? The stack trace indicates that it is currently in the process of submitting a crash report. Have you received any of such crash reports at your server yet? If so, are the crash reports possibly so large that you should not serialize them to JSON on the UI thread (causing the ANR)?

Comment: I've added the StackOverFlow link to GitHub issue.
Something like this is likely to happen.
It made so much sense :)
I will continue to research.
I'll update here if I get any results.
Thanks